# plist -- "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead

Tags: ios, swift

With Swift, I am having trouble accessing data in my `plist`.

Here's the `plist`:

```plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>Grumpy1</string>
    <string>Grumpy2</string>
    <string>Grumpy3</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

It's set to `<array>`.

I have this `Grumpy.swift' model:

```swift
import Foundation

class Grumpy: Codable {
    var name: String = ""
}
```

And this is in my `ViewController.swift`:

```swift
var grumpyArray = [Grumpy]()

let dataFilePath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("Grumpies.plist")

func loadImages() {
   if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: dataFilePath!) {
       let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
       do {
            grumpyArray = try decoder.decode([Grumpy].self, from: data)
            print(grumpyArray[1])
       } catch {
            print("Error decoding grumpy array, \(error)")
       }
    }
}
```

When I run this I get `"Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))`.

Why is it looking for a dictionary? I want it to be an array.

Comment: Please have a close look at the Plist. There is no **key** `name`.  Decode `[String].self`. And don't assign default values to struct members which are going to be decoded. The struct complies anyway.

Comment: Your structure doesn't match at all. Little tip: Let's do the reverse, so see what is matching your architecture. You used `[Grumpy].self`, so you are expecting an array of Grumpy. So let's encode that: `let array: [Grumpy] = ...; let encoder = PropertyListEncoder(); encoder.outputFormat = .xml; let encoded = try! encoder.encode(array); let stringified = String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8)!; print(stringified)`, it doesn't look like at all your plist, right? That's what your plist should look like for the decode to work... Fix either code or plist...

Comment: What should I put after `let array: [Grumpy] = `? A list of strings gave an error, `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to specified type '[Grumpy]'`.

Comment: As I said, `Grumpy` is useless. It's just a string array (`[String]`). Consider to encode to data to JSON, it's a lot of less overhead.

Comment: I don't understand. I have the outline of the array in `Grumpy.swift` and it begins `class Grumpy`

Comment: Your plist doesn't contain any **dictionary** which can be represented by `Grumpy`.

Comment: I want the `plist` to contain an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: Maybe you could write some code illustrating your idea? Thanks much.

Comment: It **does** contain an array, an array of `String`

Comment: "What should I put after `let array: [Grumpy] = `" An array of `Grumpy`. Since it's a class and not a struct, something like: `let grumpy1 = Grumpy(); grumpy1.name = "Name1"; let grumpy2 = Grumpy(); grumpy2.name = "Name2";  and then `let array: [Grumpy] = [grump1, grumpy2]`?